# Move focus to search box after search button reveals search form

Tags: html, focus

I have a search form that appears when an icon is clicked. But the focus remains on the icon, and the user has to click again inside the search box in order to be able to type. How can I shift the focus to the input box after the form appears?

My code looks like this.

**ICON:**

```
<span class="search-item">
<button aria-expanded="false" class="search-toggle">
<svg class="icon icon-search" aria-hidden="true" role="img" focusable="false">
<use href="#icon-search" xlink:href="#icon-search"></use>
</svg>
<svg class="icon icon-close" aria-hidden="true" role="img" focusable="false">
<use href="#icon-close" xlink:href="#icon-close"></use>
</svg>
</button>
</span>
```

**FORM** that opens when icon is clicked:

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" itemprop="potentialAction" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/SearchAction" action="https://www.example.com/">
<label class="label-search">
<span class="screen-reader-text">SEARCH</span>
<input type="search" class="search-field" itemprop="query-input" placeholder="Search..." value="" name="s" title="Search">
</label>
<button type="submit" class="search-submit">
<svg class="icon icon-search" aria-hidden="true" role="img" focusable="false">
<use href="#icon-search" xlink:href="#icon-search"></use>
</svg>
<span class="screen-reader-text">SEARCH</span>
</button>
</form>
```

**SEARCH FUNCTION** from functions.php:

```
public static function primary_nav_search( $args ) {
    if ( 'primary' !== $args['theme_location'] ) {
        return $args;
    }

    if ( '' === get_theme_mod('manta_nav_search', manta_get_theme_defaults( 'manta_nav_search' ) ) ) {
        return $args;
    }

    $search_toggle = sprintf( '<button aria-expanded="false"%1$s>%2$s%3$s</button>', manta_get_attr( 'search-toggle' ), manta_get_icon( array( 'icon' => 'search' ) ), manta_get_icon( array( 'icon' => 'close' ) ) );
    $search_item   = sprintf( '<span%1$s>%2$s</span>', manta_get_attr( 'search-item' ), $search_toggle );

    $args['items_wrap'] = get_search_form( false ) . $args['items_wrap'] . $search_item;
    return $args;
}
```

Can this be done, is it possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit : woops, I see no js here, but you can still use the HTML `<script>` tag**

You should consider using the *javascript* `element.blur()` to remove the focus and `element.focus()` to set the focus on another element.

More info there :

**Blur() -** https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_blur.asp

**Focus() -** https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_focus.asp

In your HTML file, try the following :

```
<script>
    const iconSearch = document.querySelector('.search-toggle');
    const searchField = document.querySelector('.search-field');

    iconSearch.addEventListener("click", function () {
        searchField.focus();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I researched this before posting, but I'm a newbie. The thing is I don't seem able to make it work. I tried setting the focus via getElementById, but it doesn't work. I think it might be because the button also shows/hides the input box?

Comment: You used getElementById but you have no id, did you try to put an id to your input ? Otherwise, if you have only 1 input like this, you can try to find the element using `querySelector` and use the class, I'll update my answer to give you some code to put in your `<script>`tag !

Comment: Yes, in the meantime I did some changes to the code and I've not updated it here. I saw other examples where they added a function to the button (onclick) and that function used getElementById, but it didn't work for me. If you'd be so kind to update your answer with the code, I'd be very grateful!

Comment: I updated my answer, the `document.querySelector('')` works with CSS selectors, if you need to put an id to your icon / input (if ever you have several of them), just put their CSS selector instead of *.search-item* and *.search-field* in my code

Comment: Did you put the sript tag in the end of your document, before the `</body>` tag ? The javascript selector can't work if it can't find the element **before** it's written, in your link in the console I can see that the selector is `null` when I open the page, and in the debugger it looks like you put the whole code a bit too early !  Otherwise I'm a bit short on solutions I fear, maybe there's in your code something that keeps the focus on the icon.

Comment: I'm sorry for that newbie mistake yet again. I moved it to the end of the body now, but it still doesn't work. Can it be a conflict with something else? I'm just wondering.

Comment: Yes, I think there is something that keep the focus on the icon, (or at least keeps the focus outside the text area, I had an issue with a router in my app that was keeping the focus on a link and I could see how "weak" this method is...

Comment: Well, I want to thank you for taking the time to explain things to me. I guess I need to dig deeper and understand the code better, then.

Comment: Wow, I did a small change and it worked! I selected the icon itself (search-toggle) instead of the span before it (search-item). And now it works! Thank you very much for your help. If you update your answer (change the css selector only from search-item to search-toggle), I will be able to accept the solution!

Comment: This time it's my bad, I should've selected the picture directly, beginner mistake....... well I edit my answer then, you're welcome !

Comment: No problem, we make a good team :)) I'm grateful for your effort and for taking the time to explain things to me!